# time calc function, php

Tags: php, wordpress

can anyone tell me why this aint working?
first kode snippert only with if works like a charm both as posted below and with a array from the mysql database index'ed in a while loop

```
<?php
$time = $_POST['modt'];
$min = 0;

if (strpos($time, ':') !== false) { 

list ($hr, $min) = explode(':',$time);

$time = (((int)$hr) * 60) + (((int)$min));

}


echo $time;
echo $min;
?>
```

but when i write it as a function its just not working.....

```
<?php
$time = $_POST['modt'];
$min = 0;

function timecalc($time, $min) {
if (strpos($time, ':') !== false) { 

list ($hr, $min) = explode(':',$time);

$time = (((int)$hr) * 60) + (((int)$min));

}
return $time;
}

echo $time;
echo $min;
?>
```

so... i'm propably an idiot overseen something.
in advance thanks! for your help :)

Comment: $min is declared globally and as a parameter.

Comment: and function even not called.

Answer (score 3):

You're not even calling the function.
You can return an array and than echo those values like below:

```
<?php
$time = $_POST['modt'];
$min = 0;

function timecalc($time, $min) {
if (strpos($time, ':') !== false) { 

list ($hr, $min) = explode(':',$time);

$time = (((int)$hr) * 60) + (((int)$min));

}
$return = array();
$return['time'] = $time;
$return['min'] = $min;
return $return;
}

$returnFromFunction = timecalc($time, $min);
echo $returnFromFunction['time'];
echo $returnFromFunction['min'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$time = $_POST['modt'];
$min = 0;

function timecalc() {
    global $time;
    global $min;
    if (strpos($time, ':') !== false) { 

        list ($hr, $min) = explode(':',$time);

        $time = (((int)$hr) * 60) + (((int)$min));

    }
    return $time;
}

echo $time;
echo $min;
?>
```

Comment: add global $time and global $min; inside function and remove  $time and $min parameter from the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$time = $_POST['modt'];
$min = 0;

function timecalc($time, $min) {
if (strpos($time, ':') !== false) { 

list ($hr, $min) = explode(':',$time);

$time = (((int)$hr) * 60) + (((int)$min));

}
return $time;
}
 $timeData= timecalc($time, $min); // Note: you need to call the function
echo $time;
echo $min;

?>
```